# Problems taking information out of if-else statements and coming up with a total order cost

Tags: java

I am having issued taking code out of my if-else statements. I need to print the order total from the information from both candies. Setting to static obviously won't work because the price will always be 0. I have tried declaring the variables elsewhere to get it to work. I probably wasn't doing it right. Thanks for helping!

```
public class Program3Main {

    String candy1 = "";
    String candy1name = "";
    double candy1price;

    String candy2 = "";
    String candy2name = "";
    double candy2price;

    int numCandy1;
    int numCandy2;

    double totalCostCandy1;
    double totalCostCandy2;
    double totalOrder;

    double totalCostCandy1p1;
    double totalCostCandy1p2;

    double totalCostCandy2p1;
    double totalCostCandy2p2;

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {

        System.out.println("          Coulter's Candy Shop\n");

        // This is the retailer section \\
        System.out.println("--------------- Retailer ---------------\n");

        // This sub-section asks the user to enter the first candies name and price.
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the first candy: ");
        Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in); // This is the scanner that will collect information.
        String candy1name=s.next();

        System.out.println("Please enter how much the first candy costs: ");
        double candy1price=s.nextDouble();


        // This sub-section asks the user to enter the second candies name and price.
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the second candy: ");
        String candy2name=s.next();

        System.out.println("Please enter how much the second candy costs: ");
        double candy2price=s.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("");


        // This is the consumer section \\
        System.out.println("--------------- Consumer ---------------\n");
        System.out.println("How many boxes of " + candy1name + " would you like to purchase?");
        int numCandy1=s.nextInt(); // Takes user input for # of candy 1.

        System.out.println("How many boxes of " + candy2name + " would you like to purchase?");
        int numCandy2=s.nextInt(); // Takes user input for # of candy 2.
        System.out.println("");

        int totalCandy = numCandy1 + numCandy2;


        System.out.println("---- Candy Units Price / Units Cost ----\n");
        // If and else statements to make sure candy 1 isn't above 12 (Determine what equation to exe) \\
        if (numCandy1 <= 12)
        {       
            double totalCostCandy1 = candy1price * numCandy1;

            System.out.println("Your boxes of " + candy1name + " cost $" + totalCostCandy1);

        }
        else if (numCandy2 > 12)// Else to calculate 5% discount on any candy amount > 12
        {
            double totalCostCandy1p1 = 12 * candy1price;
            double totalCostCandy1p2 = (numCandy1 - 12) * (candy1price * .95 );
            double totalCostCandy1 = (totalCostCandy1p1 + totalCostCandy1p2);

            double moneySavedCandy1 = (numCandy1-12) * (candy1price * .5);
            System.out.println("Your boxes of " + candy1name + " cost $" + totalCostCandy1);
            System.out.println("You saved $" + moneySavedCandy1 + "!");
            System.out.println("");
        }
        else 
        {
            totalCostCandy1 = 0;
        };


        // If and else statements to make sure candy 2 isn't above 12 (Determine what equation to exe) \\
        if (numCandy2 <= 12)
        {
            double totalCostCandy2 = candy2price * numCandy2;

            System.out.println("Your boxes of " + candy2name + " cost $" + totalCostCandy2);
            System.out.println("");

            double totalOrderp2 = totalCostCandy2;
        }
        else if (numCandy2 > 12) // Else to calculate 5% discount on any candy amount > 12
        {
            double totalCostCandy2p1 = 12 * candy1price;
            double totalCostCandy2p2 = (numCandy2 - 12) * (candy2price * .95 );
            double totalCostCandy2 = (totalCostCandy2p1 + totalCostCandy2p2);

            double moneySavedCandy2 = (numCandy2-12) * (candy2price * .5);
            System.out.println("Your boxes of " + candy2name + " cost $" + totalCostCandy2);
            System.out.println("You saved $" + moneySavedCandy2 + "!");
            System.out.println("");

        }
        else
        {
            totalCostCandy2 = 0;
        };

        totalOrder = totalCostCandy1 + totalCostCandy2;
        System.out.println("Total Cost: $" + totalOrder);

        //double totalOrder = totalCostCandy1 + totalCostCandy2;
        //System.out.println("The total cost of your order is $" + totalOrder); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What does _taking code out of my if-else statements_ mean?  What inputs are being used?  What is the output?  What is the error with the output?  The large method might be contributing to the issue.  Try moving some of the code into methods to help simplify which might reveal a better way to structure the code to achieve the desired result.

Comment: If you declare variables inside an if-else block then they can only be accessed within that block. Declare the variables inside the function and assigned values inside the if-else blocks

Comment: What do you mean by "Setting to static obviously won't work because the price will always be 0"? Static variables would work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `main(String[] args)` is a static function, meaning it belongs to the class rather than an object of a class.

The member fields that you declared in

```
String candy1 = "";
String candy1name = "";
double candy1price;
.
.
.
double totalCostCandy2p1;
double totalCostCandy2p2;
```

belong to instantiated objects of the class `Program3Main`. So these variables cannot be used. In this case you could declare these variables as static variables so they could be accessed within the scope of a static function.

```
static String candy1 = "";
static String candy1name = "";
...
```

The variables you declare inside an if-else block can only be accessed within the if-else block. You can declare the variables within the scope of the whole function and assign them values within the if-else block.

So instead of

```
if (numCandy1 <= 12) {       
    double totalCostCandy1 = candy1price * numCandy1;
    System.out.println("Your boxes of " + candy1name + " cost $" + totalCostCandy1);
}
```

do

```
double totalCostCandy1;
if (numCandy1 <= 12) { 
    totalCostCandy1 =  = candy1price * numCandy1;      
    System.out.println("Your boxes of " + candy1name + " cost $" + totalCostCandy1);
}
```